# Why vertical scrollbar doesn't appear in DataGrid WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tinyscrollbar

I need to vertical scrollbar with set MinHeight DataGrid.

But why my datagrid doesn't do that??

Here are some of my code.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=listView1, Path=MinHeight}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=listView2, Path=MinHeight}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions> .....

     <Grid Grid.Row="4">
            <DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyColumnHeader}" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}"                 
                  x:Name="incidentList" ColumnWidth="*"
                  Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="150" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectIcdtRow}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding m_IncidentListData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            .........

 <Grid Grid.Row="8">
    <DataGrid  x:Name="listView2" ItemsSource="{Binding m_ResourceList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                    
              Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyColumnHeader}" 
               ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              MinHeight="150" Margin="0,10,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
```

DataGrid at Grid.Row="4" can make vertical scrollBar,
but DataGrid at Grid.Row="8" can't.

So I use scrollViewer, but it also didn't make scrollbar. Please help me.

Comment: I've had numerous issues with scroll viewers too. Did you try setting MaxHeight too rather than just MinHeight? If you want your ScrollViewer to work you might have to set in code the MaxHeight of the ScrollViewer once you know the size of the row? (i.e. by adding a handler to SizeChanged)

Comment: What if you set the Height of the RowDefinition to 150?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ScrollViewer Height="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<Grid Grid.Row="8">
...
Your code
...
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>`

Try this, if you need only vertical ScrollViewer or horizontal ScrollViewer.